# TNT Confusion Godel Escher Bach

Tags: number-theory

In Chapter 8, around pages 258-60 there is a "Long Derivation". I follow this up to line 51 which doesn't use the previous axioms or rules of generalization, trasitivity, etc, but states "previous theorem". If one refers back to p 254-6, there is a long section on why this same string (l. 51) is unprovable. How can we prove commutability while using a theory that is unprovable.

-Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately prior to the "Long Derivation", that theorem ($\forall a: (0+a)=a$) is proved using induction. The purpose of the earlier discussion was to introduce the necessity for induction as an axiom.